# How to return customized item, instead of original item to itemwriter in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-batch

Hi I am using itemreader, processor and itemwriter, I want my writer to write only specific fields, instead of writing whole item.

For ex.

let say my model class contains below 5 field with there getter & setter method:

RECORD.CLASS

```
private String ordNo;
private String ordDate;
private String prtDctStsCd;
private String ordRefNo;
private String ordStsCd;
```

Now my processor is:

public class RecordTableProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Record, Record>{

//somecode

return item;
}

Writer: Flatfileitemwriter

**Now I want my itemwriter to write only  ordNo and ordDate field only. Instead of writing whole 5 item of record class.**

Any Idea how to do that? and
one more question how can I return only some fields from item processor instead of whole item, is there any way to return what we want?

Comment: You cannot achieve this behaviour with the same object. You need another object to do so. You can use Mapstruct library to map fields based on the configuration you provide for the Mapper object.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you map ItemReader result to Record class, then in Processor you convert your DTO object to another type, for example SpecificRecord.

```
return new SpecificRecord(record);
```

In SpecificRecord only fields that you need.

So in ItemWriter you write new SpecificRecord object.

Comment: I am a beginner, Andrew can u eleborate it little bit. I want to return only ordNo, and ordDate field instaed of all 5 field of model class, so do u mean like return new {item.OrdNo, item.OrdDate}

Comment: Your ItemReader is reading from some datasource right? File/database, nevermind. ItemReader accepts data and maps it to some object. For example Record type object.
Then you can convert this object to another object with setters and getters, right?